# Bootstrap overlay is transparent in print view IE Edge

Tags: css, ngx-bootstrap

The overlay in IE Edge is transparent when in print view. The background is a solid white in other browsers.

How can I make it a solid white background in IE Edge print view?

bootstrap v3.3.7
ngx-bootstrap v2.0.2
angular 7.2.0

[image: IE Edge overlay background is transparent]

Comment: are you using both twitter-bootstrap(with Jquery) and ngx-bootstrap in the app or just ngx-bootstrap?

Comment: only ngx-bootstrap

Comment: update your question with more details on how your trying to use the overlay (some code possibly)

Answer (score 1):

As I suppose, thats because IE and Edge removing background from elements (images and colours, making it transparent)
So I found two solutions:

1. Use `@media print` to remove any content that is not related to modal, so only modal will be visible while printing (don't forget to make modal static, so users can print two or more pages when modal content is too long), for example

```
@media print { 
    main {
      display: none !important;
    }

    sidenav {
      display: none !important;
    }

    navbar {
      display: none !important;
    }

    .modal {
      position: static !important;
    }
}
```

2. Use pseudo elements with position absolute to add image instead of background

```
@media print {
    .modal .modal-content:before {
        content: url("path/to/image");
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```